# Bluebird promise.all catch in mid promise chain and continue with promise

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Hi all thanks in advance for help.

Below is something i am trying to do

```
function1(){
   throw some error();
}
function2() {
   // dosomething successfully;
}

promise.resolve()
     .then()
     .then(
       // here i want to do promise.all and if there is any exception i want to continue with chain
      promise.all(function1, function2)
         .catch()  // handle error here only
)
     .then()
     .then()
     .catch()
```

Can anyone help me how i can achieve this. ie.while doing promise.all if there is any error in this. i donot want to break this promise chain.

Comment: The pattern at Question should return expected result where syntax is corrected and `return` included within `.then()` call before `Promise.all()`

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
Promise.resolve().then(()=> { 
  return Promise.all(promisesArray).catch((err) => console.log(err))
}).then(() => console.log('continue futher'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `.catch()` on the `Promise.all()` and you don't throw from the catch or don't return a rejected promise, then the promise chain will continue with whatever value the `.catch()` returns.

It's modeled exactly after `try/catch` where a catch, stops the exception unless you rethrow.  Similarly a `.catch()` stops the rejection unless you rethrow (or return a rejected promise) from the catch handler.

In addition, you're code flow is not quite correct.  The way you have `Promise.all()` here is not correct:

```
Promise.resolve().then(...).then(Promise.all(...).catch(...)).then(...)
```

You have to pass a function to `.then()` not the result of calling `Promise.all()` which is a promise.  And when calling `Promise.all()` you need to pass an array of promises.

You can do it like this:

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(...)
  .then(function() {
      return Promise.all([funcReturnsPromise1(), funcReturnsPromise2()]).catch(...);
  }).then(...)
```